# REGEXP_LIKE ASC numbers

Tags: sql, regex, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have string 'KK12340000' and i want to validate it only if first 4 digits after KK are in ascending order so i use something like:

```
select case when REGEXP_LIKE('KK12340000', '^KK(?=\d{4})(?:(.)\\1*|0?1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?)\d{4}$') then 1 else 0 end as valid from dual;
```

But it returns 0. So is it even possible in oracle to validate numbers in ascending order?

Comment: IMO, this is not a task that regex is good at, even though you could solve it by regex. You can create a function to check if the given string is sorted. In the function, you loop thru the input, you got `O(n)` . Now your question is `4 digits` how about `400 chars`?  are you gonna put all ascii chars in your regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT CASE
          WHEN REGEXP_LIKE (
                  'KK12230000',
                  '^KK(?:(.)\\1*|0?1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?)\d{4}$')
          THEN
             1
          ELSE
             0
       END
          AS valid
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: It works, but it also validates 1223 as valid numbers :/

Comment: Thank you, yeah I rushed a bit sorry for that, your answer works 100% now

Comment: @mAtsea. Good to hear that.

Answer (score -1):

You can try also something like this

```
SELECT 'KK12340000' LIKE 'KK%' AND 
SUBSTRING('KK12340000', 3, 1) - SUBSTRING('KK12340000', 4, 1) < 0 AND
SUBSTRING('KK12340000', 4, 1) - SUBSTRING('KK12340000', 5, 1) < 0 AND
SUBSTRING('KK12340000', 5, 1) - SUBSTRING('KK12340000', 6, 1) < 0
```